# Firebase array data delay - not submitting data whenever I submit it for the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, firebase

I am getting error when I submit my data for first time:

[image: my console]

but when I submit same data for second time it is sending.

**My code**

```
const CreateQuiz = () => {

const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
const [correctOption, setCorrectOption] = useState();
const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([
    { id: uuidv4(), option: '' },
]);


const addQuestion = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputOption = inputFields.map((inputF) => inputF.option) 
    setOptions(inputOption);
    console.log(options)
    try {
        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "examQuestions"), {
            creatorUser: currentUser.uid,
            options: options,
            correctAnswer: correctOption
        });
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
}

const handleChangeInput = (id, event) => {
    const newInputFields = inputFields.map(i => {
        if (id === i.id) {
            i[event.target.name] = event.target.value
        }
        return i;
    })

    setInputFields(newInputFields);
}

const handleAddFields = () => {
    setInputFields([...inputFields, { id: uuidv4(), option: '' }])
}

const handleRemoveFields = id => {
    const values = [...inputFields];
    values.splice(values.findIndex(value => value.id === id), 1);
    setInputFields(values);
}
```

**My return onsubmit form part:**

```
 <form onSubmit={addQuestion} style={{ width: "100%", padding: "10px 5px" }}>
                                                {inputFields.map(inputField => (
                                                    <div key={inputField.id}>
                                                        <textarea
                                                            name="option"
                                                            label="First Name"
                                                            variant="filled"
                                                            value={inputField.option}
                                                            onChange={event => handleChangeInput(inputField.id, event)}
                                                        />

                                                        <RemoveCircleOutline disabled={inputFields.length === 1} onClick={() => handleRemoveFields(inputField.id)} />
                                                        <AddCircle onClick={handleAddFields} />
                                                        <input type="radio" name='correct' value={inputField.option} onClick={(e) => setCorrectOption(e.target.value)} />
                                                        <Label htmlFor="correct">Correct</Label>
                                                    </div>
                                                ))}
                                                <div style={{ width: "100%", padding: "10px 5px", margin: "auto", textAlign: "center" }}>
                                                    <Popup
                                                        trigger={<button className="formQButton" type='submit' style={{ width: "30%", marginRight: "10px" }}> Confirm </button>}
                                                        position="top center"
                                                        nested
                                                    >
                                                    </Popup>
                                                    <button
                                                        className="formQButton" onClick={() => { close(); }} style={{ width: "30%", backgroundColor: "#ECE2E1", color: "#100F0F" }}> Close
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
```

**What I have tried:**

I have tried wrap the addDoc part with timeout function, create isloading state and also tried other delay methods but couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys the answer is sending data directly. I sent the data after storing it in state. so it updates when page rerendered itself so you should do:

```
options: inputOption
```

**instead of**

```
options: options
```